# Is it possible to run Spine animation in node.js using just .json file? (spine-runtimes library)

Tags: node.js, spine

I want to run Spine animation in node.js backend without any rendering. Is it possible to use just .json spine data for it? Because in examples I looked also require .atlas.txt file. I am using spine-runtimes library. Thanks